# Set of jQuery .click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

**Restaurant Menu**
It works how I want it to, but the way I've written the jQuery looks like it could be simplified.
How can I rewrite the jQuery so it does exactly the same thing but in much less code?
I need only the first square of JavaScript rest is only an understanding of the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Variables
  var selectedStarter = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedMain = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedDessert = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var starter = {
    firstDish: "Salad",
    firstDishPrice: 15,
    secondDish: "Soup",
    secondDishPrice: 7,
    thirdDish: "Fish rolls",
    thirdDishPrice: 12
  };

  var main = {
    firstDish: "Steak",
    firstDishPrice: 17,
    secondDish: "Salmon",
    secondDishPrice: 12,
    thirdDish: "Rissotto",
    thirdDishPrice: 9
  };

  var dessert = {
    firstDish: "Sorbet",
    firstDishPrice: 4,
    secondDish: "Fruit salad",
    secondDishPrice: 6,
    thirdDish: "Apple pie",
    thirdDishPrice: 5
  };

  function total() {
    return selectedStarter.price + selectedMain.price + selectedDessert.price;
  }

  function selectedStarterFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedStarter.price = price;
    selectedStarter.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedMainFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedMain.price = price;
    selectedMain.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedDessertFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedDessert.price = price;
    selectedDessert.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  // Instantiating HTML Button Elements
  // Starter Elements
  document.getElementById("btStarter1").value =
    starter.firstDish + ": " + starter.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btStarter2").value =
    starter.secondDish + ": " + starter.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btStarter3").value =
    starter.thirdDish + ": " + starter.thirdDishPrice;

  // Main Elements
  document.getElementById("btMain1").value =
    main.firstDish + ": " + main.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btMain2").value =
    main.secondDish + ": " + main.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btMain3").value =
    main.thirdDish + ": " + main.thirdDishPrice;

  // Dessert Elements
  document.getElementById("btDessert1").value =
    dessert.firstDish + ": " + dessert.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btDessert2").value =
    dessert.secondDish + ": " + dessert.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btDessert3").value =
    dessert.thirdDish + ": " + dessert.thirdDishPrice;

  // Your Order: Elements
  document.getElementById("selectedStarter").innerHTML =
    selectedStarter.dish + " (" + selectedStarter.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedMain").innerHTML =
    selectedMain.dish + " (" + selectedMain.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedDessert").innerHTML =
    selectedDessert.dish + " (" + selectedDessert.price + ")";

  // Functions (JQuery)
  // Main menu onClicks handler
  $("#btMenu").click(function() {
    $("#liMainMenu").toggle("slow");
  });

  $("#btStarter").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btMain").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btDessert").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  // Starter onClicks
  $("#btStarter1").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.firstDish, starter.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btStarter2").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.secondDish, starter.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btStarter3").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.thirdDish, starter.thirdDishPrice));
  });

  // Main onClicks
  $("#btMain1").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.firstDish, main.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btMain2").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.secondDish, main.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btMain3").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.thirdDish, main.thirdDishPrice));
  });

  // Dessert onClicks
  $("#btDessert1").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.firstDish, dessert.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btDessert2").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.secondDish, dessert.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btDessert3").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.thirdDish, dessert.thirdDishPrice));
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: rgb(0, 230, 40);
  outline: solid 2px #353535;
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.ul {
  display: none;
}
.table {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 43%;
}
.table th {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.table tr,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Restaurant Menu With JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" class="button" id="btMenu" value="Menu" style="background-color: #353535">
  <ul id="liMainMenu" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter" value="Starter" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain" value="Main" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert" value="Dessert" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liStarter" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liMain" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liDessert" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <table class="table">
    <th>Your Order:</th>
    <tr>
      <td>First :</td>
      <td id="selectedStarter"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Main :</td>
      <td id="selectedMain"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dessert :</td>
      <td id="selectedDessert"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total :</td>
      <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  <html>
```

[image]

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Restaurant menu that update orders and change color button

Comment: **The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code.** Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use better data structures.

When you have a problem you should try to find which data structure have more advantages for you, in this case i think that it
should be an `array`.

### Using an array.

The bigger advantage of using this approach is that is easier to remove or add new dishes to your menu, and you dont need to specificy the n-th of the dish,
you can see that using 'first'/'second' would start to become difficult for a menu with 10 options or so.

Instead of:

```
var starter = {
    firstDish: "Salad",
    firstDishPrice: 15,
    secondDish: "Soup",
    secondDishPrice: 7,
    thirdDish: "Fish rolls",
    thirdDishPrice: 12        
  };
```

You can use it:

```
var starter = [{
    dish: "Salad",
    price: 15,
} { 
    dish: "Soup",
    price: 7,
}, {
    dish: "Fish rolls",
    price: 12
}];
```

And for free you now can make your events more abstract in a way to avoid repetition:
There is one thing in HTML called [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*), its purpose is to hold some information that you need in order to identify the element; We can use it here:

```
<input type="button" class="starter-button" id="btStarter1" data-id="0" value="">
```

So as the array starts with 0, identification for the first dish is 0 as well. Now instead of creatring one event handler for each button we can abstract it to:

```
$(".starter-button").click(function() {
    // ...
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(starter[$(this).data("id")], starter[$(this).data("id")].price));
});
```

But this its just the start, you can use it better creating a even better data structure:

```
var dishes = [{
    "starter": [{
        name: "Salad",
        price: 15,
    }, { 
        name: "Soup",
        price: 7,
    }, {
        name: "Fish rolls",
        price: 12
    }],
    "desert": [...]
}]
```

Now using the same logic that before your button can be something like:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter1" data-id="0" data-type="starter" data-target-id="selectedDessert" value="">
```

And your event:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    // ...    
    var targetId = $(this).data("target-id");
    var dishType = $(this).data("type");
    var dishId = $(this).data("id");

    $(targetId).html(selectedDish(dishes[dishType][dishId].name, dishes[dishType][dishId].price);
});
```

The **tl;dr** version of my code review would be, *Try to use the best data structures for your information, and think about how would the maintenance of the code, "how can i make it so its easier to add more features?"*.

After improving this bit your code should be pretty good, keep coding!

Answer (score 3):

Like @Josenberg mentioned your data I believe would be better structured like:

```
var main = [{
    dish: "Steak",
    price: 17
},{
    dish: "Salmon",
    price: 12
},{
    dish: "Rissotto",
    price: 9
}];
```

Then to fill your elements you could use a single for loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<main.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("btMain"+(i+1).toString()).value =
      main[i].dish + ": " + main[i].price;
}
```

I would then add a class `starter`, `main`, and `dessert` to each of the respective elements. And then you could have a class on click function:

```
$('.starter').click(function(){
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var index = $(".starter").index(this);
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter[index].dish, starter[index].price));
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Variables
  var selectedStarter = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedMain = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedDessert = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var starter = [{
    dish: "Salad",
    price: 15
    },{
    dish: "Soup",
    price: 7
    },{
    dish: "Fish rolls",
    price: 12
  }];

  var main = [{
    dish: "Steak",
    price: 17
    },{
    dish: "Salmon",
    price: 12
    },{
    dish: "Rissotto",
    price: 9
  }];

  var dessert = [{
    dish: "Sorbet",
    price: 4
    },{
    dish: "Fruit salad",
    price: 6
    },{
    dish: "Apple pie",
    price: 5
  }];

  function total() {
    return selectedStarter.price + selectedMain.price + selectedDessert.price;
  }

  function selectedStarterFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedStarter.price = price;
    selectedStarter.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedMainFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedMain.price = price;
    selectedMain.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedDessertFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedDessert.price = price;
    selectedDessert.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  // Instantiating HTML Button Elements
  // Starter Elements
  for(var i=0;i<starter.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("btStarter"+(i+1).toString()).value =
      starter[i].dish + ": " + starter[i].price;
  }

  // Main Elements
  for(var i=0;i<main.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("btMain"+(i+1).toString()).value =
      main[i].dish + ": " + main[i].price;
  }

  // Dessert Elements
  for(var i=0;i<dessert.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("btDessert"+(i+1).toString()).value =
      dessert[i].dish + ": " + dessert[i].price;
  }

  // Your Order: Elements
  document.getElementById("selectedStarter").innerHTML =
    selectedStarter.dish + " (" + selectedStarter.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedMain").innerHTML =
    selectedMain.dish + " (" + selectedMain.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedDessert").innerHTML =
    selectedDessert.dish + " (" + selectedDessert.price + ")";

  // Functions (JQuery)
  // Main menu onClicks handler
  $("#btMenu").click(function() {
    $("#liMainMenu").toggle("slow");
  });

  $("#btStarter").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btMain").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btDessert").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "#008080");
      } else {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    });
  });

  // Starter onClicks
  $('.starter').click(function(){
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var index = $(".starter").index(this);
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter[index].dish, starter[index].price));
  });

  // Main onClicks
  $('.main').click(function(){
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var index = $(".main").index(this);
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main[index].dish, main[index].price));
  });

  // Dessert onClicks
  $('.dessert').click(function(){
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 230, 40)");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var index = $(".dessert").index(this);
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert[index].dish, dessert[index].price));
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: rgb(0, 230, 40);
  outline: solid 2px #353535;
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.ul {
  display: none;
}
.table {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 43%;
}
.table th {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.table tr,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Restaurant Menu With JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" class="button" id="btMenu" value="Menu" style="background-color: #353535">
  <ul id="liMainMenu" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter" value="Starter" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain" value="Main" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert" value="Dessert" style="background-color: #008080">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liStarter" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button starter" id="btStarter1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button starter" id="btStarter2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button starter" id="btStarter3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liMain" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button main" id="btMain1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button main" id="btMain2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button main" id="btMain3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liDessert" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button dessert" id="btDessert1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button dessert" id="btDessert2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button dessert" id="btDessert3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <table class="table">
    <th>Your Order:</th>
    <tr>
      <td>First :</td>
      <td id="selectedStarter"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Main :</td>
      <td id="selectedMain"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dessert :</td>
      <td id="selectedDessert"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total :</td>
      <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: I had not thought of that but rendering the elements from the objects would be a good improvement as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery and have it tagged, I want to mention that you are missing an opportunity to use it. Every time you do `document.getElementById(id)`, you could be using `$('#id)`. This is more concise, allows you use jQuery's other methods like `.html()`, `.val()` and `.data()`, and makes it easier to change the selector without needing to fundamentally change the code.

For instance, instead of

```
document.getElementById("btStarter1").value = starter.firstDish + ": " + starter.firstDishPrice;
```

you could simply do

```
$('#btStarter1').val(starter.firstDish + ": " + starter.firstDishPrice);
```

If you then needed to access nodes by class instead of id, it would be straightforward to simply change the selector:

```
$('.starterButtons').val(starter.firstDish + ": " + starter.firstDishPrice);
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why they don't agree?

Answer (score -1):

As other answers have mentioned. use better data structures to organise your data

Check this out i have made a small fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/czpy2ze3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var dishes = {
    'starters': [
        {name: 'Salad', price: 15},
        {name: 'Fish rolls', price: 33},
    ],
    'main' : [
        {name: 'Steak', price: 30},
    ],
    'desserts': [
        {name: 'Apple Pie', price: 12},
    ]
};

var types = Object.keys(dishes);

var selected = {};

$("#xMenu").click(function(){
    $("#xContent").toggle();
});

var calculate = function() {
    $("#xBill").html("");

    var total = 0;
    $xBill = $("<div>", {});
    types.forEach(function(type, index) {
        var dishindex = selected[type];
        console.log(typeof dishindex);

        if(typeof dishindex == 'number'){
            var dish = dishes[type][dishindex];
            console.log(dish);
            total+= dish.price;
            $xBill.append($("<p>",{
                html: `${type} : ${dish.name}(${dish.price})`
            }));
        } else {

        }
    });

    $xBill.append($("<h3>", {
        html: `Total: ${total}`
    }))

    $("#xBill").append($xBill);
    console.log(total);
}
var render = function() {

    var $xTypes = $("<div>", {"class": "xType"});
    var $xDishes = $("<div>", {"class": "xDishes"});

    $("#xContent")
        .html("")
        .append($xTypes)
        .append($xDishes);

    types.forEach(function(type){

        var $x = $("<button>", { "class": "xTypes", "text": type});
        $xTypes.append($x);

        var $row = $("<div>", {});
        dishes[type].forEach(function(dish, index){

            var $dish = $("<button>", {
                "class": "dish",
                "text": dish.name,
                "click": function() {
                    selected[type] = index;
                    render();
                    console.log(selected);
                }
            });


            if(selected[type] == index) {
                $dish.addClass("xchosen");
            }

            $row.append($dish);
        });

        $xDishes.append($row);

        $x.click(function(){
            $row.toggle();
        })

    });

    calculate();
};




render();


});
```

Instead of reducing code you should focus on not hardcoding the data part into your website.